# How about freezing the first row and column?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, ux-field

User may be lost when faces the massive data in a large table, how about freezing the first row and column? so that the dimensions and metrics are always reachable.

[image]
[image]
questions:

1. It would narrow down the scrolling area, is there any elegant way to get the balance right ?
2. Google Analytics doesn't commit to realize such function, for what consideration ?

thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  But is it a good idea for your design?  This is hard to answer without more specifics.  A screenshot or mockup of the design would be nice.

Comment: I would agree to dan1111 and would advise to include a screenshot so that the freezing you're suggesting is far more easier to comprehend.

Comment: We don't know enough about what you're trying to do to say whether freezing rows and columns will be useful in your situation. But freezing rows and columns for web is common enough. Some people call these "sticky" rows. e.g. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but as user I will be glad if first row and column of large table wil be frozen.

Maybe the better solution is not to freeze row and column but to create header ouside of the scrollable table?

Comment: +1 for Separate header, although can be a pain (HTML/CSS anyway) to get everything to line up unless the column widths are fixed

Comment: Just keep in mind that a seperate header object would probably effect the accessibility (in HTML it would probably break it for screen readers)